# Jquery can't update data-num value

Tags: jquery

```
//i'm using - jquery-1.11.0.js

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('div').data('num', 9); 
});
</script>
<div data-num='0'></div>
```

I try to update data-num's value, I don't know where is the problem, the value is not update.

Comment: What did you get, when you perform `alert($('div').data('num'));` after setting value? Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/198toybk/

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/r9qnmd8w/

Comment: nothing change, value still the same

Comment: "*Value still the same*" where?

Comment: div data-num still 0l let me just copy you code to see what happen

Comment: press F12(check elements from browser), the value didn't change, why?

Comment: @user2178521: changed value is not gonna reflect in console. try giving alert the way satpal has suggested.

Comment: `data()` doesn't store value in attributes. its value is saved in the cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attr()`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('div').attr('data-num', 9); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0meffmav/4/)**

Comment: @Satpal, yes you are right. I also tried your link and it is working, but just might be some other problem at OP's side hence suggested some other way. Thanks :)